# Receiving None after unmasking

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following example array:

```
import numpy.ma as ma

f_vars = np.array([[3, 4, -1, -1], 
                   [7, 8,  9, -1], 
                   [2, 3,  9, -1], 
                   [0, 1,  2, -1], 
                   [0, 2, -1, -1],
                   [0, 1,  2, -1],
                   [0, 1,  3,  4],
                   [3, 4,  5, -1],
                   [6, 7, -1, -1],
                   [6, 7, -1, -1]])
```

Then after I am masking some elements:

```
f_vars_r = ma.masked_array(f_vars_r, mask=[[0, 0, 0, 0], 
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0], 
                                           [1, 1, 1, 1], 
                                           [1, 1, 1, 1], 
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0],
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0],
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0],
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0],
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0],
                                           [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Then modifying values according to some rules in a cycle (not presented here). After that I am removing the mask, like this:

```
f_vars_r = ma.masked_array(f_vars_r, mask=[[False, False, False, False], 
                                           [False, False, False, False], 
                                           [False, False, False, False], 
                                           [False, False, False, False], 
                                           [False, False, False, False],
                                           [False, False, False, False],
                                           [False, False, False, False],
                                           [False, False, False, False],
                                           [False, False, False, False],
                                           [False, False, False, False]])
```

and expecting to see modified values on positions which were not masked and unmodified values for the elements that were masked and now with removed mask. Instead, I am receiving "None" for the unmask elements, like that:

```
 [[0 3 -1 -1]
 [6 7 8 -1]
 [None None None None]
 [None None None None]
 [1 0 -1 -1]
 [1 2 0 -1]
 [1 2 0 3]
 [0 3 4 -1]
 [5 6 -1 -1]
 [5 6 -1 -1]]
```

What is the reason behind - that I didn`t actually succeeded to remove the mask or because the mask destroyed my values? How can I recover my initial masked values?

Comment: How you modified the array matters.  The presence of `None` tells me this is an object dtype array, while the original would be `int` dtype.  When working with a masked array, it's a good idea to occasionally check the `f_vars_r.mask` and `f_vars_r.data`.

Answer (score 0):

the masked elements are actualy replaced with `None` or `1e20` or `999999` depending on the data type, this is not for protection, this is to mark them as `invalid`,
use the following line to clear the mask.

```py
f_vars_r.mask = False
```

if the mask did modify the values (this will happen if the elements are copied), then you can set them back to the original array.

```py
f_vars_r[mask] = f_vars[mask]
```

just keep in mind that the use of a masked array is to mark elements as invalid, not to protect them.

Comment: It looks masking is rather not the right thing I should do for my purpose. Is there another way of how to protect from processing/modification two particular rows in a numpy ndarray, and then just "reveal" the old content after everything else is processed accordingly? Other than that I cannot apply your first suggestion, it returns:"'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mask'"